# Plotly: How does Dash describe data without import plotly or plotly express

Tags: python, plotly, trace, plotly-dash

I am going through the Dash dashboard sample project from https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-oil-and-gas/. With the [app.py](https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/blob/master/apps/dash-oil-and-gas/app.py) file, I didn't find the px or go are imported. Instead, the data was described as dict type data such as:

```
data = [
    dict(
        type="scatter",
        mode="markers",
        x=g.index,
        y=g["API_WellNo"] / 2,
        name="All Wells",
        opacity=0,
        hoverinfo="skip",
    ),
    dict(
        type="bar",
        x=g.index,
        y=g["API_WellNo"],
        name="All Wells",
        marker=dict(color=colors),
    ),
]
figure = dict(data=data, layout=layout_count)
return figure
```

I can't find any instructions on how this was done without import px or go. Would you please let me know how this works in this particular case?

Comment: If my suggestion was useful, please consider up-voting and/or marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The necessary imports are done through

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
```

The part of the code you are referring to is a part of this callback:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("count_graph", "figure"),
    [
        Input("well_statuses", "value"),
        Input("well_types", "value"),
        Input("year_slider", "value"),
    ],
)
def make_count_figure(well_statuses, well_types, year_slider):

# [...]

    data = [
        dict(
            type="scatter",
            mode="markers",
            x=g.index,
            y=g["API_WellNo"] / 2,
            name="All Wells",
            opacity=0,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        ),
```

Notice the `Output("count_graph", "figure")` part. This says to output a `figure` to a [html.div](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/div) containing a [dcc.Graph](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph) object with `id="count_graph"`:

```
html.Div(
    [dcc.Graph(id="count_graph")],
    id="countGraphContainer",
    className="pretty_container",
)
```

Now, if you take a look under the section `Using the Low-Level Interface with Dicts & Lists`in [dcc.Graph](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph), you'll se that all it needs to produce a figure is a correctly defined dict as in the example in your question. Neither [go](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/) nor [px](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) is needed.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
```

But you *can* use [go](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/) or [px](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) if you'd like here, since any figure object produced by go or [px](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) are also structured as dicts.